# index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition. Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been seeing solutions in other questions, such as placing anonymous function to the onClick, removing things from the render, but I keep getting the same problem, the file that marks me where the problem is is the ProductCard.tsx, which has this:

```
interface PastRouteinfo {
 route: string
 paymentMethod?: string
}
interface IProps {
 settings?: Settings
 product: Product
 onProductClick?: (product: Product) => void
 onGoToCart?: () => void
 tracking?: any
 cartModel: CartModel
 hidePrice?:boolean
 history:any
 pastRouteInfo?:  PastRouteinfo
}

interface IState {
 isOpen: boolean
 showToast: boolean
 nameToRender: any
 effectivePrice: any
 offerPrice: any
}

class ProductCard extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
state: IState = {
isOpen: false,
showToast: false,
nameToRender: '',
effectivePrice: 0,
offerPrice: 0
}

componentDidMount() {
const { product } = this.props
const { name } = product

const nameToRender = this.isLongName(name) ? name.slice(0,25) + '...' :  name
const effectivePrice = product?.showPrice.price
const offerPrice = product && product.showPrice.offerPrice !== 0 && 
product.showPrice.offerPrice

this.setState({
  nameToRender,
  effectivePrice,
  offerPrice
})
}

 componentWillUnmount() {
// fix Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component
this.setState = (state,callback)=>{
    return;
};
}

onProductClick = () => {
const { onProductClick, product, history, pastRouteInfo = null } = this.props    
if(pastRouteInfo !== null) {
  this.setState({ isOpen: false })
  const data = {
    fromSuggested: true,
    product,
    pastRouteInfo,
  }
  const routeInfo = `/vendor/${product.providerId}/product/${product._id}`
  history.push(routeInfo, data)
  return
}

if (!onProductClick && pastRouteInfo === null) {
  this.setState({
    isOpen: true,
  })
} else if(onProductClick) {
  onProductClick(product)
}
}


dismissModal = () => {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    isOpen: false,
  })
}, 10)
}

setShowToast(showToast: boolean) {
 this.setState({ showToast })
}

private renderModal() {
const { isOpen } = this.state
const { product, history } = this.props
const data = {
  isOpen,
  product
}
const routeInfo = `/vendor/${product.providerId}/product/${product._id}`
history.push(routeInfo, data)
}

validateIfExistLadders = (ladder:any) => ladder && ladder.length > 0
isLongName = (name: string) => name.length >= 25 

render() {
const { product, hidePrice } = this.props
const { isOpen, nameToRender, effectivePrice, offerPrice } = this.state
const { filename, brand, ladder } = product

return (
  <Fragment>
    {isOpen && this.renderModal()}
    <div className="product-card" onClick={() => this.onProductClick()}>
      <div className="header" ></div>
      <div className="body">
        <div className="picture" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${filename})` }}>
          { this.validateIfExistLadders(ladder) &&
            <img className="img-ladder" src={small_ladder} alt="Escalonado"/>
          }
        </div>
        <div className="tp">{brand}</div>
        <div className="tp" >{nameToRender}</div>
      </div>
      {offerPrice && !hidePrice ? (
        <div className="footer offer">
          <Fragment>
             <IonText className="tp-old">
               <s>{asClp(effectivePrice)}</s>
             </IonText>
             <IonText className="tp-offer">{asClp(offerPrice)}</IonText>
           </Fragment>  
         </div>
      ) : (
        !hidePrice && 
        <div className="footer">
          <IonText>{asClp(effectivePrice)}</IonText>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  </Fragment>
)
}
}

export default track({page: 'ProductCard'})(ProductCard)
```

Comment: What is `asClp` doing?